# Powerbuilder Winsock Library Implementation

Tags: tcp, powerbuilder, winsock2

As I have to implement some winsock services in our Powerbuilder 12.5 project I have the following issue:

Suppose we have sender S that sends ( initiate communication ) data to receiver R. How can R identify the channel ( IP and port ) of sender that sender uses in order to send back to sender a reply ?

Thank you in advance for your time and cooperation.

John.

Answer (score 0):

You could call directly the winsock dll from PB (it can be trick with some API struct passing though), or you might prefer to use that [PB Winsock wrapper](http://www.topwizprogramming.com/freecode_winsock.html) that supports both TCP and UDP.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Actually I use the PB Winsock wrapper, but I do not know (even if I search a lot) exactly what function calls to use in order to achieve this! Any suggestion is kindly appreciated ...